# Unable to send mails via mini SMTP-node-server. Error: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:

Tags: docker, symfony, smtp

I have a little custom-made Node SMTP-server running on localhost, to assist with sending mails. But when I try sending a mail, I get these errors:

In Symfony:

```
{
    "message": "Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
                OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:1416F086:SSL 
                routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"
}
```

On my Node SMTP-server:

```
my-custom-smtp-server  | 
{
  "level":30,
  "time":1668095669283,
  "pid":7,
  "hostname":"1f08bad45913",
  "msg":"Got connection from 172.22.0.1"
}

my-custom-smtp-server  | 
{
  "level":50,
  "time":1668095669294,
  "pid":7,
  "hostname":"1f08bad45913",
  "msg":"SMTP Error 140413503703424:error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert 
         unknown ca:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1545:SSL alert number 48\n"
}

my-custom-smtp-server  | 
{
  "level":50,
  "time":1668095669294,
  "pid":7,
  "hostname":"1f08bad45913",
  "msg":"SMTP Error 140413503703424:error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 
         alert unknown ca:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1545:SSL 
         alert number 48\n"}
```

Can I bypass this error somehow?

I'm trying to avoid having to setup TLS and SSL on my little mini Node-SMTP-server.

**Contents of `config/packages/dev/mailer.yaml`:**

```
dsn: 'smtp://mydemo:mysuperpassword@host.docker.internal:2525'
```

**Versions and specs**

- Mac
- Symfony version 4.4

---

### Attempted solution 1: Adding `?verify_peer=false` to the DSN

I tried making the DSN-line into this (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60334349/1766219) and [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/45077#issuecomment-1085247051)):

```
dsn: 'smtp://mydemo:mysuperpassword@host.docker.internal:2525?verify_peer=false'
```

I also tried:

```
dsn: 'smtp://mydemo:mysuperpassword@host.docker.internal:2525?verify_peer=0'
```

But I get same error for both.

### Attempted solution 2: Play around with network settings

I could read here: [Trying to access host.docker.internal results in Connection refused]([https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2402#issuecomment-441059035]](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2402#issuecomment-441059035%5D) that it could be something with the host-file. However I can't find any of that in my host-file inside my container: `docker-compose exec php bash` and then `vim /etc/hosts`.

That was a post on docker-for-windows, though.

### Attempted solution 3: Try sending a mail via cURL (from inside container)

I tried to access my PHP-container (`docker-compose exec php bash`) and then send a mail with this command:

```
curl smtp://mydemo:mysuperpassword@host.docker.internal:2525 --mail-from myemail@example.org --mail-rcpt myemail@example.org --upload-file ~/email-example.txt
```

Where `~/email-example.txt` looked like this:

```
From: MyTry <myemail@example.org>
To: destinationaddress@example.org
Subject: Example email
Date: Mon, 7 Nov 2016 08:45:16

Dear Joe,
Welcome to this example email. What a lovely day.
```

And that worked! But sadly it just proves that the two containers can reach each other. And that my SMTP-server works. It doesn't solve the error I'm getting when trying to send a mail, via my SMTP-server, from the Symfony-application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do what it was stated here: [Overriding the EsmtpTransportFactory-class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61662214/1766219).

For others who aren't as experienced with Symfony (as myself).

**This goes in `config/services.yaml` (in the `services`-section):**

```
services:

  ..
  ..
  ..

  mailer.transport_factory.smtp:
    class: App\Mailer\EsmtpTransportFactory
    tags:
      - { name: 'mailer.transport_factory', priority: "-100" }
```

And the create a file: `src/Mailer/EsmtpTransportFactory.php` and put the PHP-class from the link above into that.